# Transferring database between two servers by piping

Tags: postgresql, psql

My older Postgresql servers accepts remote connections.

I'm trying to transfer the database from the old server to a new one. On the new server when logged in as root, I execute the following command

```
pg_dump -h oldserverip -U mydb -C mydb | psql -h localhost -d mydb -U mydb
```

I then get prompted with the following

"Password for user mydb: Password: "

Why is it asking for password twice?

and after I input the password, it waits there and nothing happens.

Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using the `-h` flag twice, you are being asked for password twice. The second time you are getting asked for the password, there is no prompt because the pipe `|` is masking it. If you just “trust” that the password prompt is there, and you type in the password, things will proceed.

But that’s probably not what you want to do. If the passwords for both servers are the same, you can do `export PGPASSWORD=<password>` before issuing your command. If you fee uncomfortable with this, you could use a `.pgpass` file

Another option is to set `PGPASSWORD` for both the `pg_dump` and `psql` commands, like so:

```
PGPASSWORD=<password> pg_dump -h oldserverip -U mydb -C mydb | PGPASSWORD=<otherpassword> psql -h localhost -d mydb -U mydb
```

Finally, if your `pg_hba.conf` has a `local all all trust` entry, you can simply omit the `-h localhost` arg on the `psql` side, and you’ll only be prompted for a password once.

Take your pick!

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)